# Apply background and transform transition using vue list transitions

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, css-transitions

The short: I'm having trouble understanding Vue transition groups, the offical docs, recommended practice, and how to combine all that to get what I want.

What I want is a list of items that when new ones appear they transition from green to white and slide into the list. Then when they leave, they transition from red to white and slide out of the list.

If you want what I have so far, here's a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dyllandry2/hund436m/) I made that was derived from the vue doc's [list transition example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Move-Transitions). It's almost there, the only thing that isn't working is that the leaving items don't transition from red to grey.

Everything below is what I've researched to get to this point.

---

The [official docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Classes) says I can apply transitions in `.enter-active` and `.leave-active` since they are applied throughout the entire animation.

> v-enter-active: Active state for enter. Applied during the entire
> entering phase. Added before element is inserted, removed when
> transition/animation finishes. **This class can be used to define the
> duration, delay and easing curve for the entering transition.**
>
> v-leave-active: Active state for leave. Applied during the entire
> leaving phase. Added immediately when leave transition is triggered,
> removed when the transition/animation finishes. **This class can be used
> to define the duration, delay and easing curve for the leaving
> transition.**

And later, the [List Transition docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Move-Transitions) applies the transition css statement to the element's own class instead of any of the transition classes automatically applied by vue. This makes some sense, as even the items that aren't actively leaving or entering still need to transition around those that get added or removed.

But then I stumbled upon this [github post](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/10289#issuecomment-513459150) where a VueJs member described an issue with applying transitions in `.active` classes:

> It's true that this behavior can be a bit confusing but it's actually working correctly because of the transition being applied but not being left enough time to change the color:
>
> The .leave and .leave-active classes are applied at the same time. Because element already has a background-color, this triggers a 5s transition from grey to red, but one frame after the leave class is removed and leave-to is adding, triggering a new transition to green. So the color never gets enough time to change to red.
>
> The solution is not applying the transition on leave-active but only on leave-to so the first change do not apply a transition: http://jsfiddle.net/posva/o4Lqw5ts/):
>
> The problem do not appear on enter because the browser do not get the time to render the element without enter so it appears with the blue initial color and triggers the transition from there

Comment: Landrey, If I understand what you want, you need the colours to change when the classes are injected. For that, you will need to put, colour: green in .list-complete-enter, .list-complete-leave-to and colour: red .list-complete-leave-active with this you can have a green number when adding and a red number when removing. Tell me if this is the logic you need and I can give more help if need it

Comment: In the end of the day it's the CSS that you need to play along